# Continuity of $f(x) (a^{[x]})$

Tags: continuity, indefinite-integrals

Lets assume $a$ is a constant and $f(x) = cos(\pi x)$, and $[x]$ is the greatest integer function of $x$. As far as I know $[x]$ is a discontinuous function.

Now my question:

$g(x) = f(x) (a^{[x]})$

Where $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Is $g(x)$ a continuous function? Meaning is it possible to do an indefinite integral to $g(x)$? If it is, how would that be done?

Comment: $[x]$ has jump discontinuities at integers. Try setting $a = 2$ and look at $g$ on $[0,1)$ and $[1,2)$.

Comment: I got the integral of $g$ over the interval $[0, 2]$. But how would you get the integral if it's done as indefinite integral?

Comment: In order for $g(x)$ to be continuous it would be necessary for $f(n)=0$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. For example, $f(x)=\sin{\pi x}$.

Comment: See the graph of $g$ when $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ at this desmos link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kdkzewlpov

Comment: Continuity is stronger than integrability. Your function $g$ is integrable even it has discontinuity at every integer. But I know nothing about how to find its anti-derivative.

Comment: In your example you are using $2^x$ rather than $2^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$. Have you abandoned use of the floor function in your question?

Comment: Oh yeah. Thks for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $g(x)$ is not necessarily continuous unless $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. However one can find the indefinite integral provided $f$ is integrable.

Suppose $a>0$ and $f$ is defined and integrable for $x\ge0$

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^t a^{\lfloor x\rfloor}f(x)\,dx&=&\int_0^1f(x)\,dx+a\int_1^2f(x)\,dx+\cdots+a^{\lfloor t\rfloor-1}\int_{\lfloor t\rfloor-1}^{\lfloor t\rfloor}f(x)\,dx+a^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\int_{\lfloor t\rfloor}^tf(x)\,dx\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor t\rfloor-1}\left[a^k\int_k^{k+1}f(x)\,dx\right]+a^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\int_{\lfloor t\rfloor}^tf(x)\,dx
\end{eqnarray}

To express the antiderivative as a function of $x$, let $t$ be the integration variable, then

$$ F(x)=\int_0^x a^{\lfloor t\rfloor}f(t)\,dt= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}\left[a^k\int_k^{k+1}f(t)\,dt\right]+a^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^xf(t)\,dt$$

and

$$ \int_{x_0}^{x_1}a^{\lfloor t\rfloor}f(t)\,dt=F(x_1)-F(x_0) $$

Note that this result is not as nice and compact as the antiderivative of the floor function because, unlike the floor function, $f$ is not constant on intervals $[k,k+1)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Just confirming is this also valid to use to find the antiderivative? I'm not quite sure if there is any difference between antiderivative and indefinite integral..

Comment: You would have to know the antiderivative of $f$. Then this would be the antiderivative of $g$ as a function of $t$. You could then replace the $t$ with $x$ in the final step, of course.